# How did Facebook detect that my browser window needs to be closed?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, browser

Before my post might get deleted or buried, allow me to point out that **I'm not asking for troubleshooting help. I'm just curious for a technical explanation.**

So I'm on Chrome and today, when browsing Facebook, the site showed me an in-page, Facebook-styled, dialog with the following error message:

`Sorry, something went wrong, Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.`

At first I thought this might have something to do with some exception being caught at some point and the devs pointing the user to re-initialze the page. So I refreshed the page, but I found the same error message waiting for me. I then moved on to close the current Chrome tab, opened a new one and went to Facebook again, only to see the error message again. Only indeed closing the actual browser window and re-opening fixed the error.

This made me wonder: what type of logic lives in my browser window compared to the page in a tab? How did the Facebook application gain access to objects on window level rather than being sandboxed to its own page? Doesn't Facebook just use Javascript or something that relies on JS - presumably ReactJS?

Thanks to anyone who can explain this to me.

Comment: Was it your only open browser window (i.e. did the entire browser close when you closed the window)?

Comment: it may not be that there was an error after the first time, just that farcebook is forcing you to restart the browser, which is very easily achieved without gaining any special access

Comment: @tech4him I did indeed close the entire Chrome process. I regret not opening a second window and closing the first one to see what'd have happend. Sadly I cannot reproduce the error now.

Comment: The term you need is "session". The main purpose of sessions is to see if you are logged in to an account. Browsers provide many ways of storing that include local storage and cookies.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance I'm wondering if they were storing a temporary "session cookie", which gets cleared every time you close the browser process.

MDN article on cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: sessionStorage is cleared when you close a tab. So localStorage or cookies

Comment: Still weird though, I would think that Facebook implement logic to catch an expired/corrupt cookie by deleting it and re-adding it at application level, without the need to close the window.

Comment: @sferret The answer says a "session cookie", not `sessionStorage`.